# Can we add element to the list header?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to add the image and 1 or 2 div in to the select2 element.

[image: Here is the image how I like the output from the select 2. Is it possible?]

Here is the code I tried:

```
<select style="width:94%"   id="e9">
 <option value="volvo">Suger</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
$("#e9").select2({ placeholder: 'testing',}); 
</scipt>
```

Comment: [select2 templating](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer what you actually required...

```
$("#e9").select2({
     data:'passdatahere',
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});

 function format(processElement) {
    return "<img class='flag' src='../images/i.png'/>
     <div style='display:inline-block;padding-left:15px'>" 
     + processElement.name + "</div>
     <div style='padding-left:30px'>
     <span class='icon-code-updated icon-doc-missing' style='display:inline-block'>
        </span>" + processElement.status + "</div>";
        }
```